# Accessing data from select_tag ruby widget through an ajax request to update data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ajax

I have the following select_tag within a haml file:

```
= select_tag 'setup_form_popup', options_for_select([ ["No Setup Time","0"],
["15 Minute", "15"], ["30 Minute", "30"], ["45 Minute", "45"], 
["60 Minute", "60"], ["75 Minute", "75"], ["90 Minute","90"], 
["105 Minute", "105"],["120 Minute","120"]], @event.setup_time), 
{:prompt => 'Setup Time'}
```

How can I access the data through the data attribute in an ajax request to the server? Following snippet:

```
        var setup_time_update = $.ajax({
            url: '/calendar',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: "What do I put here?";
        });
```

New to ajax so still learning the ropes. Awesome technology. Any and all help is welcomed. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get value of select tag
var setup_form_popup_value = $("#setup_form_popup").val();

$.ajax({
  url: '/calendar',
  dataType: 'json', // Are you expecting json from server? If you want to execute javascript returned from server then dataType should be 'script'.
  method: 'PUT', 
  data: { setup_time: setup_form_popup_value } // You will get params[:setup_time] in your controller.
});
```

You can refer [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation. And 
[#136 jQuery & Ajax (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)